# How to build a form for nested models?

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-1.9

I am building an app in Django 1.9 with the models Customers and Addresses:

```
class Customers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_column='NAME', max_length=400)
    email = models.CharField(db_column='EMAIL', max_length=255, unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(db_column='PHONE_NUMBER', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Addresses, db_column='ADDRESS_ID', related_name='customer_address', null=True)

class Addresses(models.Model):
    street = models.TextField(db_column='STREET', max_length=2000)
    city = models.CharField(db_column='CITY', max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(db_column='POSTAL_CODE', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, db_column='COUNTRY_ID', null=True)
```

I am new in Django, so please forgive me if this has too much mistakes.

I want to create a new Customer using a form:

```
class CustomersForm(ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Name'), widget=TextInput())
    email = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Email'), widget=TextInput())
    phone_number = forms.IntegerField(label=_(u'Phone Number'), required=False, widget=TextInput(attrs={'style': 'width:80px'}))
```

But I still want to be able to add the address. I read some stuff about nested forms, but I didn't understand.

Could you, please, help in building a form that creates a Customer with name, email, phone_number and address?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! :)

You have to override the `save` method of the form.

```
class CustomersForm(ModelForm):

    name = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Name'), widget=TextInput())
    email = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Email'), widget=TextInput())

    a_street = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Street'), widget=TextInput(), required=False)
    a_postal_code = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Postal Code'), widget=TextInput(), required=False)
    a_city = forms.CharField(label=_(u'City'), widget=TextInput(), required=False)
    a_country = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Country'), widget=TextInput(), required=False)

    # Override the save method like this
    def save(self, commit=True):
        c = super(CustomersForm, self).save(commit=False)

        # Address
        if c.address:
            a = c.address
        else:
            a = Addresses()
        a.street = self.cleaned_data.get('a_street')
        a.city = self.cleaned_data.get('a_city')
        a.postal_code = self.cleaned_data.get('a_postal_code')
        a.country = self.cleaned_data.get('a_country')

        if commit:
            a.save()
            c.address = a
            c.save()
        return c
```